# How to change Windows 10 title bars color back to white?

Tags: windows-10, title-bar

Windows 10 Build 10532 brought some requested visual improvements like a new composition with changing title bars' colors. Unfortunately I don't like the new look and I would like to bring back the white titlebars. How can I achieve it?
The only idea that comes to my mind is to apply visual style from one of the previous builds but I didn't make a backup.

Comment: Oh it finally has coloured titlebars? Awesome.

Comment: Awesome, but it would be nice to have ability to set white color as well because window titles are not readable on darker backgrounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally managed to change it by accessing legacy 'Color and Appearance'.
You can launch it by typing `rundll32.exe shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL desk.cpl,Advanced,@Advanced` in Command Prompt. There you can tweak colors and you are not limited to default set of shades.

Comment: You still can't change it back to white from there.

Comment: Yes, you can. If you set color intensity and saturation to minimum and brightness to maximum.
Another solution is to simply unchecking option 'Show color on Start, taskbar and action center' in Windows 10 Settings > Personalization > Colors.